# Node Route '/keystone//keystone/categories' in KeystoneJS Admin UI return 404 in OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, localhost, keystonejs

I met this in Node CMS KeystoneJS's admin UI, but I think this does not matter with keystone, looks like the '/' root router can not work properly in my MAC.

Here is the message I got: 

`GET /keystone//keystone/categories 404 17ms - 276b
GET /keystone/categories 200 615ms`

The full URL is: `http://localhost:3000/keystone//keystone/categories`

This can work perfectly in windows, but cannot work in OSX, no matter what browser.

Comment: does `http://localhost:3000/keystone` work?

Comment: @HarryMoreno Yes,http://localhost:3000/keystone works. But when I try to click 'create' or some other operation buttons in admin UI, it will redirect to '/keystone//keystone/something'... So that means I cannot create new items by admin UI.

Comment: that's not right. You should go to `/keystone` then click on a model. You'll be at `keystone/model` then you click on 'create model' and you should get a form to fill out or redirected to the same page with a new model added. Try asking in the keystone irc channel.